# Where to put payload on UEFI partition for it to be processed during boot (for firmware update)?

Tags: bios, uefi, firmware

I've found out many (most?) firmware require a reboot to be updated and the way it works is new firmware data is put on UEFI partition (I've got an error of ~ "cannot find UEFI partition" trying to update and got the explanation on support channel) and during next boot it is processed and used for update. Is it correct?

I assume the process uses checksums and signatures to check if new data is authentic (comes from hardware manufacturer) and valid (meant for that device). Otherwise it is an easy path for viruses. Correct?

So I don't see much risk to try update manual way: copy payload to UEFI and restart. But I could not find to what address to copy it to. Probably some bits need to be set to initialize update too. I've tried web search and reading UEFI specs (specs are rather long documents, I was not able to guess where to look based on the table of contents). TIA

P.S. In UEFI specs I've found sections "Update Capsule" and "Reset system".

***Update: WIP:*** Current question: where UEFI environment variables are stored?

From UEFI specs:

8.5.5 Delivery of Capsules via file on Mass Storage Device

As an alternative to the UpdateCapsule() runtime API, capsules of any type supported by platform may also be de-
livered to firmware via a file within the EFI system partition on the mass storage device targeted for boot. Capsules
staged using this method are processed on the next system restart. This method is only available when booting from
mass storage devices which are formatted with GPT and contain an EFI System Partition in the device image. System
firmware will search for capsule when EFI_OS_INDICATIONS_FILE_CAPSULE_DELIVERY_SUPPORTED bit in
OsIndications is set as described in Exchanging information between the OS and Firmware.

The directory EFIUpdateCapsule (letter case ignored) within the active EFI System Partition is defined for delivery of
capsule to firmware.

3.1.1 Boot Manager Programming

Programmatic interaction with the boot manager is accomplished through globally defined variables. On initialization
the boot manager reads the values which comprise all of the published load options among the UEFI environment
variables. By using the SetVariable() function the data that contain these environment variables can be modified.
Such modifications are guaranteed to take effect after the next system boot commences.

Comment: BIOS (UEFI) and Firmware updates have their own installers (not stored somewhere else) and install when you run the App. T'was always thus for my machines.

Comment: @John: T'was always thus until it changed. On most modern systems, the installer no longer has direct access to the firmware flash, instead it drops a file for the current firmware to pick up.

Comment: I think that is roughly how my systems work. The App (there are 3 on my laptop) run, immediately restart and apply the package. The post seems to imply any next reboot and that is not how this works for me. The restart for me is forced immediately.